# is it possible to still access the submitted form data?

Tags: php, forms

My main goal is to save the user's submitted form data into our MSSQL database and email service provider (iContact)

I am constraint of using iContact's page as the action attribute. Here is the example:

> < form **action="icontact.php"** id="" >

After the iContact.PHP run, it will redirect the page to my confirmation page.

So is it possible to still access the submitted form data? So I can then run my own codes to save it on my database?

Thanks!

**SIDE NOTE:** iContact is an email marketing service that I use. I have contacted iContact's developer and said that I am required to use their **icontact.php** page to be able to store my data into their email contact database.

Current Structure:

1. User fills out the Form in HTML, user submits
2. Goes to iContact php page (which I don't have control)
3. After #2 process, redirect the page into my confirmation page.

Comment: Please clarify your question: are you ALREADY logging the data into a database? Or are you trying to recover submitted data that was never logged? If the former, you can indeed use (ex. MySQL) to store the submitted form data, and retrieve it again using PHP. If the latter, then I'm afraid that unless your server is doing some serious traffic logging, then it is irrecoverable.

Comment: icontact may have this information?

Comment: @ionFish: I am trying to recover submitted data that was already been logged into icontact. I was just wondering if I can still access those data since icontact will redirect the page into my confirmation page. I apologize if its clear as mud.

Comment: So does it log to MySQL? It sounds like your PHP file is just a script that processes input. PHP itself does not log form data. Can you maybe post your source please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session for that.

simply include

```
session_start();
```

at the top of both icontact.php and nextpage.php;

then in icontact.php, you set the session variables from post variables like

```
$_SESSION['data1'] = $_POST['data1'];
//etc.
```

and in nextpage.php you store them like

```
$data1 = $_SESSION['data1'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable(field,etc) VALUES ('$data1','$etc');" , $connection);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was so focused on the problem that I fail to explain the situation very well. I've added more info on the original post. But yeah, if I had control on everything.. I would've done Sessions as well.